# Why is D2D1CreateFactory Sending an error message in assembly

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, directx, x86-64

I have a program so far all it does is tries to create a `D2D1Factory` but i get the error message `E_NOINTERFACE` and I thought I had the right `IID_ID2D1Factory` and I've checked multiple times in multiple places. Can somebody tell me why its failing and/or how to fix it.

My code

```
include externals.asm
include wincons.asm
include vtable.asm
.data
include variables.asm
;include pic.asm
include riid.asm
.code
start proc frame
    DB 48h
    push rbx
    .pushreg rbx
    push r13
    .pushreg r13
    push rbp
    .pushreg rbp
    sub rsp, 80
    .allocstack 80
    lea rbp, [rsp + 80]
    .setframe rbp, 80
    .endprolog
    mov rcx, D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED
    lea rdx, IID_ID2D1Factory
    mov r8, D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_NONE
    lea r9, ID2D1Factory
    call __imp_D2D1CreateFactory
drawscreen:

    jnc drawscreen
    xor rcx, rcx
    call __imp_ExitProcess
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    pop r13
    pop rbx
    ret
start endp
end
```

Externals.asm

```
extern __imp_GetDC:qword
extern __imp_ReleaseDC:qword
extern __imp_GetDesktopWindow:qword
extern __imp_ExitProcess:QWORD
extern __imp_SetDIBits:qword
extern __imp_BitBlt:qword
extern __imp_CreateDIBitmap:qword
extern __imp_DeleteObject:qword
extern __imp_DeleteDC:qword
extern __imp_CreateCompatibleBitmap:qword
extern __imp_SelectObject:qword
extern __imp_CreateCompatibleDC:qword
extern __imp_GetDesktopWindow:qword
extern __imp_GetLastError:qword
extern __imp_GetAsyncKeyState:word
extern __imp_D2D1CreateFactory:qword
```

Variables.asm

```
align qword
screendc qword ?
picdc qword ?
ID2D1Factory qword ?
```

Wincons.asm

```
DIB_RGB_COLORS equ <0>
SRCCOPY equ <0CC0020h>
D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_NONE equ <0>
D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED equ <0>
```

And finally riid.asm

```
IID_IUnknown    Dword   000000000h
                word    00000h
                word    00000h
                word    0C000h
                byte    000h
                byte    000h
                byte    000h
                byte    000h
                byte    000h
                byte    046h

IID_ID2D1RenderTarget   Dword   02cd90694h
                        word    012e2h
                        word    011dch
                        byte    09fh
                        byte    0edh
                        byte    000h
                        byte    011h
                        byte    043h
                        byte    0a0h
                        byte    055h
                        byte    0f9h

IID_ID2D1Factory    Dword   006152247h
                    word    06f50h
                    word    0465ah
                    word    09245h
                    byte    011h
                    byte    08bh
                    byte    0fdh
                    byte    03bh
                    byte    060h
                    byte    007h
```

Comment: D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_NONE is supposed to be passed by reference, not by value.

Comment: when i create a variable with the value of D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_NONE and lea r8 to it it has the same error code

Comment: I assumed it would, but it was still a mistake in your code.

Comment: Your third `word` value in the GUID should be `04592h` rather than `09245h` (or, more properly, it should be `byte 092h, byte 045h`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't define the UUID for IID_ID2D1Factory correctly. The problem is that the Microsoft binary encoding of UUIDs requires that the last two components of the UUID {06152247-6f50-465a-9245-118bfd3b6007} be in big-endian format, unlike the first three components which are in little-endian order.  So it should be:

```
IID_ID2D1Factory    Dword   006152247h
                    word    06f50h
                    word    0465ah
                    byte    092h
                    byte    045h
                    byte    011h
                    byte    08bh
                    byte    0fdh
                    byte    03bh
                    byte    060h
                    byte    007h
```

Instead of defining this UUIDs yourself, it would be easier and less error prone to use the definitions in `uuid.lib` included in the Windows SDK.